# OneHot Encoding a full String dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have dataframe which has 6 Columns with `string` type of data(All data are in String type). I want to encode data to binary vector for training in `Keras` , `Tensorflow`.

```
  Llower  Lupper   Lbody        OpenStyle       CloseStyle  Color
0   long  middle    long   open_equal_low   open_equal_low  green
1  equal   short    long   open_equal_low   open_equal_low    red
2  equal  middle  middle  open_equal_high   open_equal_low    red
3  equal   short  middle  open_equal_high  open_equal_high  green
4  short   short  middle   open_equal_low  open_equal_high    red
```

I tried to encode them to `int` and after that to `binary vector`. 
My code for converting to `int`:

`df = df.apply(labelEncoder.fit_transform)`

result:

```
   Llower  Lupper  Lbody  OpenStyle  CloseStyle  Color
0       1       2      1          2           2      1
1       0       3      1          2           2      2
2       0       2      2          1           2      2
3       0       3      2          1           1      1
4       3       3      2          2           1      2
```

And when I tried to convert them with `to_categorical`:

```
df.Llower = to_categorical(df.Llower,num_classes=4)
df.Lbody = to_categorical(df.Lbody,num_classes=4)
df.Lupper = to_categorical(df.Lupper,num_classes=4)
df.OpenStyle = to_categorical(df.OpenStyle,num_classes=5)
df.CloseStyle = to_categorical(df.CloseStyle,num_classes=5)
df.Color = to_categorical(df.Color,num_classes=3)
```

result:

```
   Llower  Lupper  Lbody  OpenStyle  CloseStyle  Color
0     0.0     0.0    0.0        0.0         0.0    0.0
1     1.0     0.0    0.0        0.0         0.0    0.0
2     1.0     0.0    0.0        0.0         0.0    0.0
3     1.0     0.0    0.0        0.0         0.0    0.0
4     0.0     0.0    0.0        0.0         0.0    0.0
```

This is wrong converting of data to binary vector. 
How can I encode correctly data to binary vector?(or what ever Tensorflow/Keras train without any problem)

My second question:

After encoding data,I have to convert them to `Np Array` which is all `float64` with this code `dataset = df.values` . Does this data type converting (`binary vector` to `float64`) makes any problem for training quality? How can the data remained as `binary vectory` after converting them to `Numpy Array`?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you want for the first question, but I believe pandas get_dummies would work for you, once your data is in a data frame.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html For the second question, I've not personally had any issues converting between np arrays and pd dataframes, with a range of machine learning algorithms, and in this case as it is just a categorical number, I would not expect to. Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use dummy columns, which you can make using [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html). In short, this creates columns of zero or one for each level of the factors in your original dataframe. It's a common way of dealing with categorical data for machine learning, including for use in neural networks. For example:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True)
```

Which returns:

```
   Llower_long  Llower_short  Lupper_short  Lbody_middle  \
0            1             0             0             0   
1            0             0             1             0   
2            0             0             0             1   
3            0             0             1             1   
4            0             1             1             1   

   OpenStyle_open_equal_low  CloseStyle_open_equal_low  Color_red  
0                         1                          1          0  
1                         1                          1          1  
2                         0                          1          1  
3                         0                          0          0  
4                         1                          0          1
```

I used `drop_first=True` because you only need `n-1` columns, where `n` is the number of levels per category, as the rest of the information is redundant. You can omit that argument if you want to keep all columns for one reason or another